# If I say I am 'interested' in a position, does that imply certainty in my decision

Tags: word-choice, expression-choice

I am considering accepting a position at a company, however I do not want to talk with certainty just yet. If I say that I am 'interested' in that position, would that be appropriate for my situation?

Comment: Consider posting this in [workplace.se], which may be a more appropriate audience.

Comment: "Interested" implies that you would seriously consider the position but are not ready to commit to it without further discussion/consideration.

Comment: For future reference, when submitting a question, you might want to make the title question align with the description. For example, "How do I say I'm interested in a position without expressing certainty?" Just a thought. You seem to be neutral in your question but want guidance to a particular outcome in your description. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, definitely.

You could say *I'm interested, please tell me more*.

In British English, it's very common for someone to say simply *'interesting'* when they are offered something in informal circumstances. It expresses interest without commitment.

Comment: Ahem. In *British* English, ***That's interesting*** often really means [*I literally could not care less about what you’re saying*](http://www.hexjam.com/uk/news/21-things-british-people-say-vs-what-they-mean). Alternatively it can mean *That's really f@cking weird!* (in a "negative" way).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - "That's interesting" can mean the same things in the US.  But "I'm interested" wouldn't, and even with "That's interesting" context is king -- it would only be taken ironically if somehow said or written dismissively.

Comment: @FunbleFingers - Indeed, ***That's** interesting* can mean that, but only when uttered in an affected, sarcastic way. Therefore, when said like so, it comes across as very rude, and is thus quite uncommon. The only time I can think that it might be used is by a senior employee to a junior. In England, it is very common for someone to say *interesting* in a slow, emphatic manner if they are indeed genuinely interested.

Comment: And of course there's ["very interesting"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a6g9lfGnFx0).